# Getting Google Analytics campaign data charts with Google API and PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

Yes. I would like to retrieve GA Campaign Tracking Data but don't know how to do with PHP. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/ which is a php library for accessing such data. There are a few examples which I think show it quite well.

Hope it's of help.